# It must have been love, but

Tags: modal-verbs

... but it’s over now.

I remembered one episode which took place 6 or 7 years ago. I was at the English class, and the teacher was an American student who had been asked to be a teacher just for one lesson, as a treat.

So, for some reason she mentioned this song (‘It must have been love’ by Roxette). Maybe the topic was about modal verbs. Then she said (I think, to herself rather than to students): “This phrase ‘it must have been love’ sounds so nineteen eighties. I wouldn’t say like that.”

And I never had chance to ask her WHY. Why does it sound nineteen eighties? What would she say instead? Can grammar get old-fashioned in this short period of time?

Comment: Probably not the grammar, rather the idea being expressed. But only your teacher can say why she thought so.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with grammar. The expression is still considered grammatical, but it does sound rather sickly-sentimental to anyone other than a person talking to themself about their own experiences. Perhaps we've lost something over the last 30-odd years. //   I like the interchange between Tauriel and Thranduil in the third Hobbit film (you can check to see if I'm remembering it correctly): "Why does it hurt so much?" ... "Because it was real."

Comment: I'm not an English speaker. So I thought what she meant is clear/obvious to other English speakers. @Jim

Comment: Do you imply being sentimental is a thing of nineteen eighties (and before)? @EdwinAshworth

Comment: (Comment 1): No; grammar and style are distinct. A sentence can be perfectly grammatical, but unacceptable for other reasons (dangerous ambiguity, falsity, nonsense, poor style ...). // (Comment 2): Sentimentality isn't what it used to be, in my experience.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is there a way to express grammatically this idea in a more neutral way? (Maybe: I think it was love)

Comment: The *song* "It must have been love" sounds very 80s, but I don't agree that the phrase itself sounds 80s. Are you sure you heard her correctly? Your quotation “This phrase ‘it must have been love’ sounds so nineteen eighties. I wouldn’t say like that.” doesn't sound like phrasing a native English speaker would use.

Comment: @nnnnnn You've never taught English?

Comment: @nnnnnn It happened several years ago. I can't cite her. Why I thought she referred to the phrase is that the fact the song from the 80s is obvious to sound 80s, so it's not worth mentioning at all. And that's why I have written here, to clear this all up.

Answer (score 3):

Grammar can indeed go out of style, but there does not seem to be much evidence that the phrase *it must have been love* is particularly connected to the 80s—other than the fact that it was the title of one very popular 80s song which was featured in a very popular movie from 1990, *Pretty Woman*.

**Discussion**

A well-known exaple of a grammatical construction going out of style is the decline of the subjunctive in British English (see e.g. [this discussion](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/the-subjunctive) at Collins Dictionary). Some more recent examples are listed in [this](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/51362/4-changes-english-so-subtle-we-hardly-notice-theyre-happening) Mental Floss article:<sup>1</sup>

1. a shift from *they started to walk* to *they started walking*;
2. an increase in the use of the progressive mood;
3. an increase in the use of *going to, have to, need to, want to*;
4. an increase in the use of *get*-passive (e.g. *they got promoted*).

<sup><sup>1</sup>The article says that it 'draws on work' by linuistis Mark Davies, Geoffrey Leech, and Christian Mair, but it doesn't give specific references.</sup>

Here is another example:

> Over the past few decades, three new ways of reporting speech have appeared:
>
> (4) So Karen goes, "Wow - I wish I'd been there!"
>
> (5) So Karen is like, "Wow - I wish I'd been there!"
>
> (6) So Karen is all, "Wow - I wish I'd been there!"
>
> In (4), *goes* means pretty much the same thing as *said*; it's used for reporting Karen's actual words. In (5), *is like* means the speaker is telling us more or less what Karen said. If Karen had used different words for the same basic idea, (5) would be appropriate, but (4) would not. Finally, *is all* in (6) is a fairly new construction. In most of the areas where it's used, it means something similar to *is like,* but with extra emotion. If Karen had simply been reporting the time, it would be okay to say *She's like, "It's five o'clock,”* but odd to say *She's all, "It's five o'clock”* unless there was something exciting about it being five o'clock.
>
> Is it a lazy way of talking? Not at all; the younger generation has made a useful three-way distinction where we previously only had the word *said*.
>
> from [*Is English Changing?*](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/english-changing) by Linguistic Society of America

But I would add that in these (spoken!) contexts, it would sound a bit stilted and formal to actually use the word *said*.

[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) records the following two cases of grammatical constructions that may sound old-fashioned to some speakers:

> **Stative have: lexical or auxiliary (*doesn't have* vs *hasn't*)**
>   In AmE stative *have* always behaves as a lexical verb (and is preferred over *have got*). In BrE the lexical use has become common too, and the auxiliary use is tending to sound relatively formal or **old-fashioned** (with *have got* or lexical *have* preferred). (p. 113)

and

> Non-deontic *shall* is not wholly restricted to 1st person subjects. Some speakers allow it in 2nd person interrogatives like *Shall you take a taxi?*, where *Will you take a taxi?* is likely to be taken as a request rather than a question about your intentions. This use is uncommon and for many speakers sounds **old-fashioned** and formal; the more usual way of avoiding the request interpretation is by use of the progressive *Will you be taking a taxi?* (p. 195)

***It must have been love***

However, as this Google NGramm shows, there is no obvious decline in the use of "it must have been love" in the *written* English since the 1980s:

[image]

Nor is there any evidence on Google NGram for a significant decline in the usage of *must have been*:

[image]

In the Corpus of Historical American English [(COHA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/), there is some evidence that the construction *must have been* declined in popularity somewhat since the 70s, but has remained fairly constant since the 80s:

decade         1950     1960      1970     1980     1990     2000
words per    39.40    36.03    35.73    28.40    29.10    25.53
million

Having said all this, I have to admit that I don't have access to a corpus that records youth vernacular over time, and perhaps there one might find the tendency mentioned by your student-teacher. But equally possible is that that tendecy was local to that student-teacher's local environment—or that she was simply mistaken.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Very useful to know. You mentioned 4 cases of changing. Can you say that the structures that are being substituted now sound outdated?

Comment: @PabloDescamisado Maybe not outdated, but rather bit formal for normal speech. I do understand that you are particularly interested in phrases that now sound old-fashioned, but didn't sound that way 30 or so years ago. I'll look more.

Comment: @PabloDescamisado For what it's worth, I tend to think that timescales for grammar begining to sound old-fashioned are much longer than the corresponding timesclaes for words and idioms (you can't use *groovy* these days with a straight face). Moreover, *new* grammatical constructions can appear, but their 'standard' counterparts then seem to become more **formal**-sounding as a result, much more so than old-fashined-sounding. I've added a relevant example in my answer (with *So Karen goes, "Wow - I wish I'd been there!"*).

Comment: @PabloDescamisado I've added two examples of grammatical constuctions that CGEL says may sound old-fashined.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Yes, I call it help. Well, when something begins sounding formal/old-fashioned, does it draw extra attention to a speaker? E. g. if I told 'I haven't got the keys' or something like that, would people's reaction be like 'Man relax, speak normally' or 'Why is he speaking that way?'

Comment: @PabloDescamisado *I haven't got the keys* makes you sound British. What would make you sound old-fashioned is *I haven't the keys.* If a native speaker actually used that phrase in speech, people would probably assume that he or she is making a sort of joke (similarly to using a phrase from Shakespeare). With non-native speakers, other speakers make allowances and will just ignore it as an awkward construction non-native speakers sometimes make.

Comment: On no page of ESL grammar references is there a mention of the fact it IS possible to say “I haven't the keys”. Moreover, it would be considered a mistake, like “I swimn't” or “I eatn't” :-)

Comment: @PabloDescamisado Well, it is definitely **not** a mistake, whereas * *swimn't* and * *eatn't* definitely are. You saw that CGEL, the leading comprehensive English grammar, records such usage of *have*. Moreover, *I haven't the* occurs 158 times in COCA and 66 times in the BNC. Examples include *Why lie? I haven't the faintest idea*; *I haven't the time or the patience for it*; *I haven't the heart to tell him yet*; etc. It is old-fashioned, borderline archaic, but it is not a mistake.

Comment: Oh, I have failed to make it clear... I know it's correct, because I actually saw it in books and heard in films! But it happened way after I learned to use it. And I remember that in books it wasn't suggested as an option (I can see why now)